# iOS Metal: Why does this seemingly unrelated shader code change cause anti-aliasing to break?

Tags: ios, metal, fragment-shader

I'm new to Metal and my OpenGL experience is probably around a decade old at this point.

I'm wondering if someone can help me figure out why a seemingly unrelated shader change cause the aliasing to break.

Here is a rough example of my fragment code, which works and shows nicely aliased images (I'm using SampleCount of 4 inside a MTKView)

```
fragment float4 mesh_fragment(ColorInOut in [[stage_in]],
                              bool frontFacing [[front_facing]],
                              constant uniforms_t& uniforms [[ buffer(0) ]])
{
    float4 col = in.color;
    float4 d = fwidth(col);
    float4 f = step(d * 2.0, col);
    float minBary = min(f.x, min(f.y, f.z));
    if (minBary == 0.0)
        return float4(0, 0.243, 0.110, 1.0);

    // Some basic height map colour calculations ommited
}
```

Basically, does a simple fwidth+step to make a wire frame, and theres some code to alter the colour based on height, but it produces a decent image below...

[image: No Aliasing issues]

Ignore the grid, and the intersecting plane, I'm just talking about the psychadelic mesh. The wire frame looks fine.

If I add some extra code to simply render another thicker 'wireframe' style line in red at a specific height, the code works *but* all the other wireframe lines become jagged and lose their anti-aliasing.

Heres the 'new' lines added to the shader...

```
fragment float4 mesh_fragment(ColorInOut in [[stage_in]],
                              bool frontFacing [[front_facing]],
                              constant uniforms_t& uniforms [[ buffer(0) ]])
{
    float4 col = in.color;
    float4 d = fwidth(col);
    float4 f = step(d * 2.0, col);
    float minBary = min(f.x, min(f.y, f.z));
    if (minBary == 0.0)
        return float4(0, 0.243, 0.110, 1.0);

    // NEW LINES
    float clipDistance = abs(uniforms.cutLevel - in.color.a);
    float clipD = fwidth(clipDistance);
    float clipF = step(clipD * 4.0, clipDistance);
    if (clipF == 0.0)
        return float4(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    // END

    // Some basic height map colour calculations ommited
}
```

Below you can see the new image, this time with the Red highlight line being drawn fine, but everything is now more jagged.

[image: More jagged wireframe]

I appreciate my shader code is likely not great, but I just don't understand whats even going on here to cause this?

I thought maybe I was hitting some limit on the total number of computations happening, but even if I leave the code in and just comment out the if + return for the Red line, it then renders crisp with the anti-aliasing working fine just like in the first image.

Any ideas/advice?

Comment: Interestingly, if I simply change this line...

```if (clipF == 0.0)```

To 

```if (clipDistance < 0.05)```

The thickness of the red line is obviously bad and not workable - but - the aliasing issue is gone.

I'll admit - I don't truly understand fwidth. But I'm at a loss a bit as to why I'm seeing the Barycentric wireframe being affected by this other check.

Comment: Ok, zooming into the jagged image, I can see bits of 'red' on the Wireframe.

So I guess I'm wondering why the other check is also succeeding on the wireframe edges.


For extra information,

The in.col is a float4 where I'm using all 4 channels,
XYZ/RGB is the Barycentric coordinate and used for wireframe
A/W is a normalised 'height' between 0-1, and uniforms.cutLevel is a value between 0 and 1 to render a 'line' in red.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as always, I 'solve' it just after posting to ask the question after spending nearly 2 days trying to figure this out.

I'll admit I don't really know *why* I need to do this so some advice would be great, but I've 'simplified' my fwidth call to only occur once.

Before, I did an fwidth on the in.col for the wireframe, then an fwidth on the in.col.a for the Red cut line.

Now I do one fwidth on the in.col but use 2 step functions, so now I do this...

```
float4 col = float4(in.color.xyz, abs(uniforms.cutLevel - in.color.a));
float4 d = fwidth(col);
float4 f = step(d * 2.0, col);
float minBary = min(f.x, min(f.y, f.z));
if (minBary == 0.0)
    return float4(0, 0.243, 0.110, 1.0);

float4 f2 = step(d * 4.0, col);
if (f2.a == 0.0)
    return float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

This seems to work fine now.

Anyone able to help explain :D ?